# How to capitalize the first letter (with a diacritic) of string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to convert to lowercase some strings/sentences, like this: "**ȘEF DE CABINET**", then to convert to uppercase only *the first letter of the first word* (**with a diacritic**) of these strings. I found [a function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php#99081) that will convert the first letter *of every word* from the string. How to adapt it to my needs?

This is the code:

```
function sentence_case( $s ) {
   $s = mb_convert_case( $s, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8' );
   $arr = preg_split("//u", $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
   $result = "";
   $mode = false;
   foreach ($arr as $char) {
      $res = preg_match(
         '/\\p{Mn}|\\p{Me}|\\p{Cf}|\\p{Lm}|\\p{Sk}|\\p{Lu}|\\p{Ll}|'.
         '\\p{Lt}|\\p{Sk}|\\p{Cs}/u', $char) == 1;
      if ($mode) {
         if (!$res)
            $mode = false;
      } 
      elseif ($res) {
         $mode = true;
         $char = mb_convert_case($char, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
      }
      $result .= $char;
   }

   return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, this is what I've used (thank @ben-pearl-kahan for the correct direction!):

```
function sentence_case( $string ) {
   $string = mb_strtolower( $string, 'UTF-8' ); //convert the string to lowercase
   $string_len = mb_strlen( $string, 'UTF-8' ); //calculate the string length
   $first_letter = mb_substr( $string, 0, 1, 'UTF-8' ); //get the first letter of the string
   $first_letter = mb_strtoupper( $first_letter, 'UTF-8' ); //convert the first letter to uppercase
   $rest_of_string = mb_substr( $string, 1, $string_len, 'UTF-8' ); //get the rest of the string
   return $first_letter . $rest_of_string; //return the string converted to sentence case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr` to retrieve just the first character and do it on that:

```
function sentence_case( $x ) {
   $s = substr($x,0,1);
   $s = mb_convert_case( $s, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8' );
   $arr = preg_split("//u", $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
   $result = "";
   $mode = false;
   foreach ($arr as $char) {
      $res = preg_match(
         '/\\p{Mn}|\\p{Me}|\\p{Cf}|\\p{Lm}|\\p{Sk}|\\p{Lu}|\\p{Ll}|'.
         '\\p{Lt}|\\p{Sk}|\\p{Cs}/u', $char) == 1;
      if ($mode) {
         if (!$res)
            $mode = false;
      } 
      elseif ($res) {
         $mode = true;
         $char = mb_convert_case($char, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
      }
      $result .= $char;
   }

   return $result.substr($x,1); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose that `substr` do not work correctly for letters with diacritics, as a result I got a "�ef de cabinet".

Comment: Try it with `mb_substr`, setting the encoding to UTF-8: `substr($x,0,1,'UTF-8')`

Comment: I think the code lines `$s = substr($x,0,1); $s = mb_convert_case( $s, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8' );` must be changed to `$x = mb_convert_case( $x, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8' ); $s = mb_substr($x,0,1,'UTF-8');`. In this case the result is better, but not definitively: `Ș�ef de cabinet`. What is wrong?

Comment: Because the line `$x = mb_convert_case( $x, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8');` converts to lowercase all letters of the string, that can be initially in uppercase, and I need to convert to uppercase only the first letter of the first word, this function can be shortened?